# Google Apps Scripts - My button will not call the javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This is the html code user input form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="marginauto" align="middle">

  <style>
    .marginauto {
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    }
  </style>
  
  <h1>
    <img class="marginauto" align="middle" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=********" alt="*****">
    Fabrication Time Record
  </h1 >

  <h2 class="marginauto" align="middle">
    Information
  </h2>

    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
    <label for="jnum">Job number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="jnum" name="jnum"><br>

  <h2>
    Operation
  </h2>

    <input type="radio" id="cut" name="operation" value="cut">
    <label for="cut">Cut</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="drill" name="operation" value="drill">
    <label for="drill">Drill</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="fitup" name="operation" value="fitUp">
    <label for="fitup">Fit Up</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="weld" name="operation" value="weld">
    <label for="weld">Weld</label><br>

  <h2>
    Comments
  </h2>

  <input type="text" id="comment"><br>

  <br>
  <button id="clockin">Clock in</button>

  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      document.getElementById("clockin").addEventListener("click",addLine);

      function addLine(){

      var firstName = document.getElementById("fname");
      var lastName = document.getElementById("lname");
      var operation = document.getElementByName("operation");

      var entry = {
        entry.fn = firstName.value;
        entry.ln = lastName.value;
        entry.op = operation.value;

      }

        google.script.run.addEntry(entry);
        firstName.value = "";
        lastName.value = "";

      }

    </script>
            
</body>

</html>
```

This is the script that takes user inputs from the html and (ideally) transfers them to a google spreadsheet:

```
function doGet(e){

  Logger.log(e);
  
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("userForm");
  html.setTitle("Record Time")
  return(html)

}


function addEntry(entry){

  Logger.log("Someone clicked the button");

  var ssid = "1E81*****************QBmW1o4Q";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var database = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(database);

  database.appendRow = ([entry]);

}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. I am sure that I am calling the correct spreadsheet because I can read and write from the doGet() function, but there seems to be a problem with the addLine() function that I cannot find.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am very new to web app development.

What I want is for the button to transfer the data from some text input fields to a google spreadsheet. I used multiple different button syntaxes but cannot nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object to `addEntry` you should pass an array.

Change

```
  var entry = {
    entry.fn = firstName.value;
    entry.ln = lastName.value;
    entry.op = operation.value;
  };
```

To

```
  var entry = [
    firstName.value,
    lastName.value,
    operation.value
  ];
```

Also you have a typo in your client script.  Change

```
var operation = document.getElementByName("operation");
```

To

```
var operation = document.getElementsByName("operation");
```

However `getElementsByName` returns a node list so to find the checked radio button you need to add this to your client script.

```
let operations = document.getElementsByName("operation");
let operation = null;
for( let i=0; i<operations.length; i++ ) {
   if( operations[i].checked ) {
     operation = operations[i];
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your change and still ran into the same issue. I think I've narrowed it down to something to do with: var operation = document.getElementByName("operation");   Whener I commented that line out and didn't pass it into the function it works. Thank you for taking the time, I truly appreciate it.